# installing package "sjstats" gives error non-zero exit status

Tags: r

I am trying to install package sjstats. I am using Rstudio. I tried commands install.packages("sjstats") and install.packages("sjstats", dependencies=TRUE), but I always get the same error. I get a series of errors for all the packages included. Here is an example:

ERROR: dependencies 'rlang', 'sjlabelled', 'sjmisc', 'tidyr' are not available for package 'sjstats'
* removing '***'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '*****' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘sjstats’ had non-zero exit status.

Do you have any hint on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: try to install it in R not Rstudio

Comment: Try to install the packages mentionned in the error and then install your package.

Comment: I tried, I still have a similar errors for one of the missing packages:           
installing vignettes
Warning in file(con, "w") :
  cannot open file '***R/win-library/3.2/R6/doc/index.html': No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing vignettes failed
* removing '***R/win-library/3.2/R6'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "***R\win-library\3.2" C:****/R6_2.2.2.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘R6’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Alice, I tried to use R, but it did not work.

Comment: It could be that you need to update R, maybe some packages require R > 3.2